# How to create a custom Newtonsoft.Json nuget to use in my .NET Core 3.1 app?

Tags: json, json.net, nuget

### Issue:

How can I use a custom build of Newtonsoft.Json in my project which forces the transitive nuget packages to use my custom package?

### Details:

We are using Newtonsoft.Json and have stumbled across a bug in it. There's an [open PR to fix it](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/1679), but it's going no where.

Instead, I've forked, patched and created my own nuget package - works fine!

Now, I've got a 3rd party nuget package which has an older version of Newtonsoft.Json in it .. and now it's complaining that I need to use that specific version. When I manually use the most recent version explicitly in my project, there's no errors from the transitive versions. Hmm.. okay. When I use *my* version, it complains saying it wants to transitive version added.

[image]

My guess is that my custom build of Newtonsoft.Json has `publicKeyToken=null` where as the official ones are `publicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed`

I also don't believe I can sign the custom dll to have the same `publicKeyToken`? (Side note: There is a Strong Name Key file in the repo, though. I'm not sure if i can use this?)

So is there anything I can do?

Is there a way to say to all transitive nuget packages to use *my* version of Newtonsoft.Json instead of the older, official one?

### Update

- Here's a repo of the problem: https://github.com/PureKrome/Custom-NSJson-NotWorking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the repo there are two reasons because it doesn't build:

1. Assmebly version `11.0.0.0` but dependencies require `12.0.0.0`.

You can fix that by increasing the version number of the dll.

2. Mismatching signature.

You can fix this by [test- / delay-signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/delay-sign) the .dll with the public key that Newtsoft.Json.dll uses or has in the repo (didn't check if the key in that repo is the one used for signing).

You can accomplish both with the included dll in that repo by:

(Done in a VS command prompt to have all the tools in place)

1. Extract the public key from a public version of Newtonsoft.Json with `sn -e Newtonsoft.Json.dll nsjson.snk` (suggest `C:\Users\YOURUSER\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\12.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0` if NuGet downloaded that previously)
2. IL-disassemble the dll using `ildasm.exe /all Newtonsoft.Json.dll /outfile=Newtonsoft.Json.il`
3. Change the `.ver 11:0:0:0` specification in the .il file to `.ver 12:0:0:0`
4. Copy over `nsjson.snk`. Then reassemble and delay sign the assembly with `ilasm.exe /dll /key=nsjson.snk Newtonsoft.Json.il`

For this to work I used the ilasm/ildasm versions from the `microsoft.netcore.ilasm` and `microsoft.netcore.ildasm` 5.0.0 NuGet packages (e.g. `C:\Users\YOURUSER\.nuget\packages\microsoft.netcore.ilasm\5.0.0\runtimes\native\ilasm.exe` if you installed these packages into any project)

Comment: For other readers - I manually built another version of `Newtonsoft.Json` with the correct version updated in the `.csproj` and also used the exported public key (from @martinullrich 's code, above) which is easy to delay sign using visual studio or hard coding the stuff i the `.csproj` file

Answer (score 1):

> Side note: There is a Strong Name Key file in the repo, though. I'm not sure if i can use this?

Yes, if there’s a key that you can use, then you should use it to recreate a signed package. Assembly signing is a remnant from the past when there was the .NET Framework with its Global Assembly Cache (GAC). The GAC required all assemblies to be signed as some means to protect shared assemblies from being quietly overwritten by a third party. Many packages were signed just in case someone needed to deploy the assembly through the GAC.

In the world of open source where everyone should be able to recreate a package, keeping the key secret didn’t really make much sense. It also isn’t *really* a protection (like [signing a NuGet package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/sign-a-package) would be). Instead, it is just a thing that you need to do in order to allow users to consume the assembly via the GAC. Most open source packages eventually started to add the key to their repo.

So you should try to create a signed package for your Newtonsoft.Json fork, if the key isn’t protected (didn’t check this but you should easily find out once you try using it).

Once you have a valid package, you will have to make it available though. So you will need to create a package source that comes *before* NuGet.org to avoid the original Newtonsoft.Json from being resolved instead. You should also make sure to clear your local NuGet cache since your updated package with the same version will not automatically replace the existing version.

---

If that all doesn’t help, and that other library still attempts to resolve to a different assembly version, then you could also configure a custom handler that intercepts the assemble resolve process.

I’ve used the following code in the past to remove a hard dependency on an older version of Newtonsoft.Json that some library had that I needed to use. When an unresolved assembly gets requested and that name happens to be `"Newtonsoft.Json"` (with whatever version and public key token), then I instead return whatever Newtonsoft.Json assembly I have around (that being a newer version, or even possibly an unsigned fork) and resolve to that one instead:

```cs
private static Assembly RedirectNewtonsoftJsonAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    var assembly = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
    if (assembly.Name != "Newtonsoft.Json")
        return null;

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= RedirectNewtonsoftJsonAssembly;
    return Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert));
}
```

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += RedirectNewtonsoftJsonAssembly;
```